# Need cause for: double dialer icon in Recents when ACTION_CALL is intercepted and re-sent

Tags: android

Note that this happens on Android version 2.1 update1 and 2.2. This seems gone in later versions.

Of course I would like to know the **workaround**. But **if there are none**, at least if this is a **known bug**, please provide with a **link to the bug**. I would also accept the source code fix info or diff where this was fixed.

I have an application that intercepts an outgoing call, asks a question to the user, and then depending on the answer it could re-send the call. This works fine.

But then when you go to the Recents (hold the Home key) there are two slightly different dialer icons there: one from the dialer application, and a second one for the resending of the call action: [image: See the image]

This means when you click on the first icon, it opens the dialer. But when you click on the second one, it redials the last number.

I tried using `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` for all my activities. I also tried `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` when I start the call action. No luck.

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for call interception and re-sending?

Comment: I am assuming Emmanuel's code is intercepting NEW_OUTGOING_CALL in a BroadcastReceiver and then start an Activity which in turn start an ACTION_CALL intent. However, I just tried this using the emulator for 2.1 and 2.3 and both seems to work fine (no extra dialer icon is shown in the Recents screen).